# Auto-refresh webpage using jQuery with an on-off button

Tags: jquery, button, refresh

I would like to auto-refresh my webpage using jQuery with an on-off button. However, I tried my code but it is not work at all. Anyone knows what are the problems?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btnautorefreshon").click(function(){
        setTimeout(function() { location.reload() },1500);
        });
    });
</script>
```

The following is the code of on-off button:

```
<div class="page-header-actions" data-toggle="buttons" role="group">
             <label class="btn btn-outline btn-primary active">
             <input type="radio" name="options" autocomplete="off" value="autorefreshoff" checked />
             <i id="btnautorefreshoff" class="icon wb-check text-active" aria-hidden="true"></i>                        Auto Refresh Off
             </label>
             <label class="btn btn-outline btn-primary">
             <input type="radio" name="options" autocomplete="off" value="autorefreshon" />
             <i id="btnautorefreshon" class="icon wb-check text-active" aria-hidden="true"></i>                        Auto Refresh on
             </label>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: anyone knows the problems?

Answer (score 0):

The radio button for the autocomplete is an `input` tag in your html, and so you just need to refocus your selector label to address this by adding a unique id to the input itself.

```js
/* $(".btn").on({
  'click': function() {
    if ($('input#refreshon').is(':checked')) {
      console.log('checked');
      setTimeout(function() {
          location.reload();
      }, 1500);
    }
  }
}); */

$('input#refreshon').on({
  'click': function() {

    console.log('checked');
    setTimeout(function() {
      location.reload();
    }, 1500);

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-header-actions" data-toggle="buttons" role="group">
  <label class="btn btn-outline btn-primary active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" autocomplete="off" value="autorefreshoff" checked />
    <i id="btnautorefreshoff" class="icon wb-check text-active" aria-hidden="true"></i> Auto Refresh Off
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-outline btn-primary">
    <input id="refreshon" type="radio" name="options" autocomplete="off" value="autorefreshon" />
    <i id="btnautorefreshon" class="icon wb-check text-active" aria-hidden="true"></i> Auto Refresh on
  </label>
</div>
```